# LoadBalancer Controller not working in AWS EKS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I created eks cluster with eksctl and deplyed app , service and ingress but no loadbalancer has been created :(

kubectl version 1.23.6

eksctl version : 0.165.0

for Load Balancer Controller Installation i followed this guide https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/deploy/installation/

Describe pod

```
kubectl describe pod  techcare-apigw-65f496dd85-f8s28 -n techcare                                                                                                        ✔  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  10:36:20  
Name:         techcare-apigw-65f496dd85-f8s28
Namespace:    techcare
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-192-168-17-235.eu-central-1.compute.internal/192.168.17.235
Start Time:   Fri, 08 Dec 2023 22:09:36 +0100
Labels:       app=techcare-apigw
              pod-template-hash=65f496dd85
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.3.4
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.3.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/techcare-apigw-65f496dd85
Containers:
  techcare-apigw:
    Container ID:   containerd://cbf1050a4aca263fbc86c97c759dda48694dc637fe1da40dbf0430319d5da5ef
    Image:          435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.57
    Image ID:       435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway@sha256:e362e6e1bf42002b510dff2a621e85e7f1fc304a1fef5c02095919129b0a0f45
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 08 Dec 2023 22:10:12 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-q92s4 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      Tre 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-q92s4:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  27m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned techcare/techcare-apigw-65f496dd85-f8s28 to ip-192-168-17-235.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Normal  Pulling    27m   kubelet            Pulling image "435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.57"
  Normal  Pulled     26m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.57" in 34.870208122s (34.870944373s including waiting)
  Normal  Created    26m   kubelet            Created container techcare-apigw
  Normal  Started    26m   kubelet            Started container techcare-apigw
```

Describe ingress

```
kubectl describe ing example-ingress -n techcare                                                                                                                         ✔  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  10:36:37  
Name:             example-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        techcare
Address:          
Default backend:  techcare-apigw-s:80 (192.168.3.4:3000)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /   techcare-apigw-s:80 (192.168.3.4:3000)
Annotations:  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: alb
Events:       <none>
```

Describe service:

```
kubectl describe service techcare-apigw-s  -n techcare                                                                                                                   ✔  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  10:35:56  
Name:              techcare-apigw-s
Namespace:         techcare
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=techcare-apigw
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.100.50.10
IPs:               10.100.50.10
Port:              http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        3000/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.3.4:3000
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        3000/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.3.4:3000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Manifest deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: techcare-apigw
  namespace: techcare
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: techcare-apigw
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: techcare-apigw
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: techcare-apigw
          image: 435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.57
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: techcare-apigw
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: techcare-apigw-s
  namespace: techcare
spec:
  selector:
    app: techcare-apigw
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
      name: http
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 3000
      name: https
  type: ClusterIP
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: techcare
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: alb
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: techcare-apigw-s
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: techcare-apigw-s
                port:
                  number: 80
```

pods:

```
 kubectl get po -A                                                                                                                                                    127 ✘  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  10:46:37  
NAMESPACE     NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   aws-load-balancer-controller-75776fdbcf-wrl5l   1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system   aws-load-balancer-controller-75776fdbcf-xms7t   1/1     Running   0          41m
kube-system   aws-node-6n9ph                                  1/1     Running   0          63m
kube-system   aws-node-g4fnw                                  1/1     Running   0          63m
kube-system   aws-node-h8j7n                                  1/1     Running   0          63m
kube-system   aws-node-vfchz                                  1/1     Running   0          63m
kube-system   coredns-7bc655f56f-8mr27                        1/1     Running   0          73m
kube-system   coredns-7bc655f56f-jqtlx                        1/1     Running   0          73m
kube-system   kube-proxy-5bw4p                                1/1     Running   0          63m
kube-system   kube-proxy-925qt                                1/1     Running   0          63m
kube-system   kube-proxy-h96kj                                1/1     Running   0          63m
kube-system   kube-proxy-n4x9f                                1/1     Running   0          63m
techcare      techcare-apigw-65f496dd85-f8s28                 1/1     Running   0          37m
```

load balancer controller logs:

```
kubectl logs aws-load-balancer-controller-75776fdbcf-wrl5l -n kube-system                                                                                                ✔  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  10:46:48  

{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","msg":"version","GitVersion":"v2.6.2","GitCommit":"5e07dced064969588164c60cd493ce7921e913da","BuildDate":"2023-10-27T19:20:16+0000"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"controller-runtime.metrics","msg":"Metrics server is starting to listen","addr":":8080"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"setup","msg":"adding health check for controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"Registering webhook","path":"/mutate-v1-pod"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"Registering webhook","path":"/mutate-v1-service"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"Registering webhook","path":"/validate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta1-ingressclassparams"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"Registering webhook","path":"/mutate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta1-targetgroupbinding"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"Registering webhook","path":"/validate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta1-targetgroupbinding"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"Registering webhook","path":"/validate-networking-v1-ingress"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:24Z","logger":"setup","msg":"starting podInfo repo"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:26Z","logger":"controller-runtime.webhook.webhooks","msg":"Starting webhook server"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:26Z","logger":"controller-runtime.certwatcher","msg":"Updated current TLS certificate"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:26Z","logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"Serving webhook server","host":"","port":9443}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:26Z","msg":"Starting server","path":"/metrics","kind":"metrics","addr":"[::]:8080"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:26Z","msg":"Starting server","kind":"health probe","addr":"[::]:61779"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-12-08T21:05:26Z","logger":"controller-runtime.certwatcher","msg":"Starting certificate watcher"}
I1208 21:05:26.950628       1 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease kube-system/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader...
```

```
 kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces                                                                                                                                     ✔  18.10.0 Node  18.10.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  11:06:12  

NAMESPACE   NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
techcare    example-ingress   <none>   *                 80      54m
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I will recommend you to bump your AWS EKS to 1.27 or 1.28 first, remember the controller not working out of the box, you need to give rights for it, if you use AWS CDK you can see my code snippet here.

I will strongly recommend applying core functions to your AWS EKS with AWS CDK to make your ground system more transparent for you and your team.

**Apply LoadBalancer with helm:**

```
def __install_load_balancer_controller(self, cluster: eks.Cluster):
    service_account = "aws-loadbalancer-controller-sa"

    aws_alb_sa = eks.ServiceAccount(
        self,
        "AWSLoadBalancerController",
        cluster=cluster,
        namespace="kube-system",
    )
    with open(
        os.path.join(
            "infrastructure/k8sStack/iam-policy/loadbalancer-controller/iam-policy.json"
        ),
        "r",
    ) as f:
        policy_document = json.load(f)
        for s in policy_document.get("Statement"):
            policy_statement = iam.PolicyStatement.from_json(s)
            aws_alb_sa.add_to_principal_policy(policy_statement)

    eks.HelmChart(
        self,
        "eks-aws-load-balancer-controller",
        cluster=cluster,
        chart="aws-load-balancer-controller",
        repository="https://aws.github.io/eks-charts",
        release="aws-load-balancer-controller",
        namespace="kube-system",
        version="1.6.1",
        values={
            "clusterName": cluster.cluster_name,
            "serviceAccount": {
                "create": False,
                "name": aws_alb_sa.service_account_name,
            },
        },
        wait=True,
    )
```

**iam-policy.json:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:GetCoipPoolUsage",
                "ec2:DescribeCoipPools",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "acm:DescribeCertificate",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACL",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACLForResource",
                "waf-regional:AssociateWebACL",
                "waf-regional:DisassociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACLForResource",
                "wafv2:AssociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:DisassociateWebACL",
                "shield:GetSubscriptionState",
                "shield:DescribeProtection",
                "shield:CreateProtection",
                "shield:DeleteProtection"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "CreateSecurityGroup"
                },
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/app/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetIpAddressType",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "elasticloadbalancing:CreateAction": [
                        "CreateTargetGroup",
                        "CreateLoadBalancer"
                    ]
                },
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetWebAcl",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```